# Exporting a Column to .csv: Avoiding Four Zeros in Cells with Over 15 Digits

Tags: python, html, pandas

First of all, I'm totally new in Python and programming world and I would need your help please.

**Problem: Keep the original numbers from a specific column of an HTML file on a .csv file. **

I am currently running a script that identifies a game provider and a website from an HTML file and exports the information as a .csv file. It is crucial that the 'ROUND_ID' column retains the exact same numbers as in the original file, as it is provided to our specialized team in Excel format.

Unfortunately, Excel is appending four zeros at the end of the number, even altering the correct last four digits to zeros. As a temporary workaround, I have managed to add a " at the beginning of each cell to maintain the desired format. However, I am actively seeking a permanent solution that can retrieve the original number without any modifications.

I tried to run a script that converts column to Text but it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions?

CODE BELOW:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os

# Set the directory path containing the HTML files
directory = 'C:/Users/gusta/Downloads/HTML/'

# Create an empty list to store the extracted data
filtered_data = []

# Step 1: Loop through each HTML file in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        # Read the HTML file
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            html_content = file.read()

        # Parsing the HTML content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

        # Filtering the data
        data_rows = soup.find_all('tr')  # Find all table rows
        for row in data_rows[1:]:  # Skip the header row
            cells = row.find_all('td')

            # Handle variations in table structure
            if len(cells) >= 13:
                trader_id = cells[3].text.strip()  # Extract trader ID from the fourth column
                name = cells[5].text.strip()  # Extract name from the sixth column

                # Apply desired filters (e.g., trader ID and name)
                if trader_id == '513' and name == 'PG Soft':
                    # Extract other required columns here
                    collected_data = [
                        cells[0].text.strip(),
                        cells[1].text.strip(),
                        cells[2].text.strip(),
                        trader_id,
                        cells[4].text.strip(),
                        name,
                        cells[6].text.strip(),
                        cells[7].text.strip(),
                        cells[8].text.strip(),
                        cells[9].text.strip(),
                        cells[10].text.strip(),
                        cells[11].text.strip(),
                        cells[12].text.strip()
                    ]
                    # Convert ROUND_ID to a string surrounded by quotes
                    collected_data[7] = f'"{collected_data[7]}"'

                    # Append the collected_data list to filtered_data
                    filtered_data.append(collected_data)
            else:
                print("Unexpected table structure. Skipping row...")

# Generating a single DataFrame from all the extracted data
df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_data, columns=[
    'CUSTOMER_BET_ID',
    'CUSTOMER_CODE',
    'USERNAME',
    'TRADER_ID',
    'TRADER_NAME',
    'NAME',
    'UID_',
    'ROUND_ID',
    'PLAYED_DATE',
    'S',
    'CSN_GAME_ID',
    'PLAYED_AMOUNT_FROM_BALANCE',
    'GAME_NAME'
])

# Save the DataFrame to a single CSV file with a semicolon (;) as the delimiter
output_file = 'output.csv'
df.to_csv(output_file, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, quotechar='"', sep=';')
print(f'Data extraction and spreadsheet generation completed. Output saved to {output_file}.')
type here
```

- I tried adding " before and after the ID - it can help as a workaround, however, the provider still needs to copy the numbers and remove the " by themselves.
- Tried to format the columns as Text but the script didn't work.

Comment: For example:

Original ROUND_ID: 1660382709472047104
What is being generated: 1660382709472040000

Comment: Please [edit] your question with sample data demonstrating the problem.

Comment: You will have to treat those as strings.  Excel simply cannot handle integers that large, so they are getting converted to doubles, which only keep 15 or so digits.

Comment: Hello @TimRoberts, thank for your reply. I have tried to set up the code as strings but it always generates with the same results. The ROUND_ID appears as scientific format.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    ... = f'"{collected_data[7]}"'
```

This is charming, but ultimately ineffective, as excel just ignores your efforts.

If you want to import a .csv with 19-digit IDs like 1660382709472047104 into excel,
you cannot make it look like a [number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Consider transforming those IDs into ones with a string prefix,
such as `"X"`, which excel will not mangle:

```
                    ... = f'X{collected_data[7]}'
```

You can strip the prefix later in the data processing pipeline
once the values are out of the clutches of the unfaithful excel component.